Terms of Closed Form for Logarithmic Integrals

Does the closed-form expression for the integral $$I_n = \int_{0}^{1} \log^n(1+x)\log^n(1-x) \text{ $dx$}$$ only involve terms that can be written solely in terms of zeta functions, powers of logarithms of 2, and rational numbers?


$I_0$ is evidently $1$.
For $n=1$, we have
$$I_1 = \int_{0}^{1} \log(1+x)\log(1-x) \text{ $dx$} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} \log(1+x)\log(1-x) dx \overset{1+x=2t}{=} \int_{0}^{1} \log{2t} \log{(2(1-t))} dt$$
$$= \log^2(2)\int_{0}^{1} dt + 2\log(2)\int_{0}^{1} \log(1-t) dt + \log(2) \int_{0}^{1} \log(t)dt + \int_{0}^{1} \log(t) \log(1-t) dt$$
$$ = \log^2(2) - \log(2) - \log(2) + 2 - \zeta(2) = \boxed{\log^2(2) - 2\log(2) + 2 - \zeta(2)}$$
(approximately $-0.5507$)
Each term in $I_1$ can be written solely in terms of zeta functions, powers of logarithms of 2, and rational numbers.

For $n=2$, we have
$$I_2 = \int_{0}^{1} \log^2(1+x)\log^2(1-x) \text{ $dx$}$$
Consider the algebraic identity $A^2B^2 = \frac{1}{12}((A+B)^4 + (A-B)^4 + 2A^4 - 2B^4)$.
Let $A = \log(1-x)$, and $B = \log(1+x)$. Using the aforementioned identity and logarithmic properties, we see that
$$I_2 = \dfrac{1}{12}\underbrace{\int_0^1\log^4(1-x^2)dx}_{\Gamma_1}+\dfrac{1}{12}\underbrace{\int_0^1\log^4\left(\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}\right)dx}_{\Gamma_2}-\dfrac{1}{6}\underbrace{\int_0^1\log^4(1-x)dx}_{\Gamma_3}-\dfrac{1}{6}\underbrace{\int_0^1\log^4(1+x)dx}_{\Gamma_4}$$
See this post on the evaluation of $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2, \Gamma_3, \Gamma_4$. OP required the evaluation of $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2$. $\Gamma_1$ can be nicely evaluated using the reduction formula method. The other integrals have nicer closed forms, in terms of the zeta function.
$$\Gamma_1 = 384 -384\log(2) + 192\log^2(2) - 16\pi^2 - 96\zeta(3) - 64\log^3(2) + 16\pi^2\log(2) + 96\zeta(3)\log(2) - 8\pi^2\log^2(2) + 16\log^4(2)-\frac{3}{5}\pi^2$$
$$\Gamma_2 = 42\zeta(4)$$
$$\Gamma_3 = 24$$
$$\Gamma_4 = 2\log^42-8\log^32+24\log^22-48\log2+24$$
I will not go into the full details of the simplification. By replacing terms involving $\pi^2$ with those using $\zeta(2)$, and combining like-terms, we see that
$$I_2 = \frac{1}{12}\Gamma_1 + \frac{1}{12}\Gamma_2 - \frac{1}{6}\Gamma_3 - \frac{1}{6}\Gamma_4 = \boxed{24 - 8\zeta(2) - 8\zeta(3) - \zeta(4) + 8\log(2)\zeta(2) - 4\log^2(2)\zeta(2) + 8\log(2)\zeta(3) - 24\log(2) + 12\log^2(2) - 4\log^3(2) + \log^4(2)}$$
(approximately $0.7962$)
Each term in $I_2$ can be written solely in terms of zeta functions, powers of logarithms of 2, and rational numbers.

For $n$, we have
$$I_n = \int_{0}^{1} \log^n(1+x)\log^n(1-x) \text{ $dx$}$$
Consider the definition of the Beta function
$$B(x,y) = \int_{0}^{1} u^{x-1}(1-u)^{y-1} du \overset{1-2u = t}{\Rightarrow} \int_{-1}^{1} (1-t)^{x-1} (1+t)^{y-1} dt = 2^{x+y-1}B(x,y)$$
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\partial^{2n}}{\partial x^n \partial y^n}((1-t)^{x-1} (1+t)^{y-1}) dt = \frac{\partial^{2n}}{\partial x^n \partial y^n}(2^{x+y-1}B(x,y))$$
$$\int_{-1}^{1} (1-t)^{x-1} (1+t)^{y-1} \log^n(1-t) \log^n(1+t) dt = \frac{\partial^{2n}}{\partial x^n \partial y^n}(2^{x+y-1}B(x,y))$$
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \log^n(1-t) \log^n(1+t) dt = \lim_{\substack{x\to 1 \\ y\to 1}} \frac{\partial^{2n}}{\partial x^n \partial y^n}(2^{x+y-1}B(x,y))$$
$$\int_{0}^{1} \log^n(1-t) \log^n(1+t) dt = \frac{1}{4} \lim_{\substack{x\to 1 \\ y\to 1}} \frac{\partial^{2n}}{\partial x^n \partial y^n}(2^{x+y}B(x,y))$$
Can each term in $\frac{1}{4} \lim_{\substack{x\to 1 \\ y\to 1}} \frac{\partial^{2n}}{\partial x^n \partial y^n}(2^{x+y}B(x,y))$ (for all $n$) only be written solely in terms of zeta functions, powers of logarithms of 2, and rational numbers?
Thanks.

Edit
This post was closed for being a duplicate. I have since changed the problem (it has not received any answer yet). The problem focuses on just the terms of the closed for expression for $I_n$, instead of the general case of $I_n$.
Now, these are two different problems. For this post, a solution will involve proving $\frac{1}{4} \lim_{\substack{x\to 1 \\ y\to 1}} \frac{\partial^{2n}}{\partial x^n \partial y^n}(2^{x+y}B(x,y))$ will only contain terms soley using zeta functions, powers of logarithms of 2, and rational numbers. The "duplicate post" focuses on a general form to $\frac{1}{4} \lim_{\substack{x\to 1 \\ y\to 1}} \frac{\partial^{2n}}{\partial x^n \partial y^n}(2^{x+y}B(x,y))$
Thank you.

$\int_{0}^{1} \log^3(1-x) \log^3(x+1) , dx = 36 \zeta(3)^2 + 12 \pi^2 \zeta(3) - 216 \zeta(3) - 144 \zeta(5) + 36 \zeta(3) \log^3(2) \

108 \zeta(3) \log^2(2) - 12 \pi^2 \zeta(3) \log(2) + 216 \zeta(3) \log(2) + 144 \zeta(5) \log(2) - \pi^4 - 36 \pi^2 - \frac{23 \pi^6}{420} + 720 \


\log^6(2) - 6 \log^5(2) - \frac{3}{2} \pi^2 \log^4(2) + 30 \log^4(2) + 6 \pi^2 \log^3(2) - 120 \log^3(2) - \frac{1}{2} \pi^4 \log^2(2) \


18 \pi^2 \log^2(2) + 360 \log^2(2) + \pi^4 \log(2) + 36 \pi^2 \log(2) - 720 \log(2)$


(to OP) Unsuprisingly, the closed form is always an algebraic combination of $\log(2)$ and $\zeta(s)$ due to the fact that the derivatives of $2^x$ generate $\log(2)$ and derivatives of $B(x,y)$ generate polygamma(integer) which can be written as zeta functions here. Your last formula is already good, I don't expect someone will expand it out for you.
